# SharePoint search returns no results

Tags: iis, sql-server-2008, sharepoint, sql

We have a SharePoint (WSS 3.0) web application, https://projects.mydomain.com, and we have about 5 sites on this web app. SharePoint search works fine on all these sites. We just set up a company intranet on another domain name that we use, https://office.myOTHERdomain.com, but when I try to search for items on this site, I get an error that says "No results matching your search were found.".

In SharePoint, both sites are setup to use the same accounts for search. Since the search works for the first domain, that account obviously has login permissions on our SQL Server. Can anybody help me figure out why search is not working in the second domain? I'm not seeing any errors in the SharePoint log or Event Viewer, except for an occasional error related to SharePoint Services Search that says "Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication". But it doesn't say what account this refers to, and anyway, as I noted, the account we are using seems to work for our other web app. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, we backed up the intranet, took it down, and then recreated it from scratch, and that fixed the problem. I'm not sure what ultimately caused the problem. Thanks for all the input.

Answer (score 0):

I would check under the Search Administration page in Central Admin.  Specifically check the Crawl Log to see what kind of errors you are getting while crawling this other domain site.

HTH, Dan

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using WSS, not MOSS, and as far as I know, it doesn't have a crawl log.

Comment: oh, in that case are you using the native WSS Search engine or MS Search Server Express?  I'm pretty sure with the native WSS Search engine, you can't crawl anything outside of it's own SharePoint sites.

Comment: I'm using native WSS search. I'm not trying to crawl outside of the site. I want to stay within the office.myOTHERdomain.com site; but I'm getting no results.

Comment: Sorry, I completely misunderstood your original question.  I thought you were trying to search across domains.  So you're talking about 2 separate WSS web apps running on 2 different domains, with search working on one, but not the other.  Is that correct?  Do both WSS web apps point to the same SQL Server?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, and they both point to the same SQL Server, and are using the same accounts to access it.

Comment: The search engine actually crawls the SharePoint websites in order to catalog the content for search.  It sounds like you are using an account created in one domain to try and crawl content in other domain.  You will need to create a trust between the two domains so that both SharePoint sites can authenticate the account.  If that isn't feasible, then you will need to create a second account within the domain of your intranet SharePoint, that can be used to crawl the data.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on the same issue.  The account its referring to is the default content access account.  Also, you can find crawl logging for WSS within the WSS Search database.